# how to match the letter "$" in c when use regex.h?

Tags: c, regex

there is a string:

> "fdsfsfsfsfsdomnol$natureOrder(0123)jqnm"

I want to match the substring:$natureOrder(0123),I do something like this:

```
regcomp(&reg, "\$natureOrder\([0-9]{1,4}\)", cflags);
```

but it doesn't work!How to write the regex pattern?

Comment: If you change the regex in your question by taking the one of my answer, my answer doesn't make sense anymore... Why do you do this ?

Comment: i type wrong just now,but i use this it didn't work too.

Comment: It is not particularly good manners to change the question after people start answering.  If the change occurs in the first 5 minutes, there isn't a record of the original version that people can refer to (for older questions, the first version is frozen and people can take the material from the original and embed it in their answer along with an explanation of why their answer addresses the original — and can adapt to the modified question too).  @dystroy: When it is feasible, I quote the original question in my answer, then address the revised question.  There's not much else you can do.

Comment: AFAICR, the original proposed regex was `"\$natureOrder\[[0-9]{1,4\]"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart escaping the `$`, you need to have the parenthesis in your regex, and those ones too must be escaped.

So the regular expression would be

```
\$natureOrder\([0-9]{1,4}\)
```

And when in a C string, as the `\` is the start of an escape sequence :

```
regcomp(&reg, "\\$natureOrder\\([0-9]{1,4}\\)", cflags);
```

Comment: And since the string has to be C, you have to double up each backslash to get the correct result: `"\\$natureOrder\\([0-9]{1,4}\\)"`.